# Find the first instance of a value in a list

Tags: excel, vba

This code:

```
RPName_rng = Cells.Find(What:=RPName, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

gives me the last instance of a value in a list. It works well.  I need to find the first instance of that value instead of the last and then use that as the top left anchor of a range to be named.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about using `xlNext`? `RPName_rng = Cells.Find(What:=RPName, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub dural()
    Dim RPName As String, RPName_rng As Long
    RPName = "happiness"
    RPName_rng = Cells.Find(What:=RPName, After:=Cells(1, 1), _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    MsgBox RPName_rng
End Sub
```

This will find the first occurrance.

Comment: Thank you Gary's Student

Comment: Gary's Student's answer correctly gives me the location of the first instance in the list. The code I was using gave me the last instance of the same value. Both of them defined the Row number. Now I need to use those numbers to define a range. I tried Range(RPName,Cells(RPName_rng, 18) ).Name = "data4" but that gives me an error

Comment: should use `xlNext` to ensure the search occurs in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you could use just the "RPName_rng = Cells.Find(What:=RPName)" part. The search goes from the 1st cell in the search range ("cells" in your case, meanning "everywhere"). All you need to do is to  ***first check if the "Cells(1)=RPName" in case it's in the first cell***.

Comment: Gary's Student's answer correctly gives me the location of the first instance in the list. The code I was using gave me the last instance of the same value. Both of them defined the Row number.  Now I need to use those numbers to define a range.  I tried 

Range(RPName,Cells(RPName_rng, 18) ).Name = "data4" 

but that gives me an error

Comment: Range(RPName,Cells(RPName_rng, 18)) is wrong. It's either range("Address") or cells(col, row). Maybe you need "RPName_rng.Row"?

Comment: the range will be somethng like A:21-R:31.  The row numbers will be RPName_rng1 and RPName_rng2.  I can't figure out how to do that in the Range( . . . ) line.